# While loop only displaying one result

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with the below code? For some reason it's only returning one result. I have checked to see how many rows are being returned from the query using mysql_num_rows() and it says two, so why do I only see one result?

```
function get_events($amount) {
    global $wpdb;
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $result = mysql_query(
        "SELECT
            wp_eventscalendar_main.eventTitle, wp_eventscalendar_main.eventDescription, wp_eventscalendar_main.eventStartDate, wp_eventscalendar_main.postID, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value 
         FROM
            wp_eventscalendar_main, wp_postmeta
         WHERE
            STR_TO_DATE('$today', '%Y-%m-%d') < wp_eventscalendar_main.eventStartDate AND
            wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_eventscalendar_main.postID AND
            wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
         ORDER BY wp_eventscalendar_main.eventStartDate ASC
         LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

     $thumbpostid = $row['meta_value'];

     $result2 = mysql_query("
     SELECT
        post_id, meta_key, meta_value
     FROM
        wp_postmeta
     WHERE
        post_id = $thumbpostid AND
        meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'") or die(mysql_error());

     while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $thumburl = explode(".",$row2['meta_value']); 
     }

     $shortdesc = limitWrds($row['eventDescription'], 10);

     $rawdate = date('d M', strtotime($row['eventStartDate']));
     $date = explode(' ', $rawdate);

     $postlink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $row['eventTitle']))); 

      echo "<div class=\"event\">
                <div class=\"txt\">
                    <h5><a href='/" . $postlink ."'>" . $row['eventTitle'] . "&sbquo;&nbsp;" . $date[1] ."&nbsp;" . $date[0] . "</h5></a>
                    <p>" . $shortdesc ."&hellip;&nbsp;
                    <a href=\"" . $postlink . "\">find out more &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><img src='/wp-content/uploads/". $thumburl[0] ."-42x42.jpg' alt='". $row['eventTitle'] ."' />
            </div>";
            echo _clear('15');    
      }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: look on log if you have an error while run the code, maybe in the second row some fields empty like $row['eventDescription'] and occurs an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all that code into the second while loop. You are basically overwriting the first row.

```
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $thumburl = explode(".",$row2['meta_value']); 
 }
```

It's probably looping twice, but you only have 1 variable.

Should be:

```
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $thumburl = explode(".",$row2['meta_value']); 

    $shortdesc = limitWrds($row['eventDescription'], 10);

    $rawdate = date('d M', strtotime($row['eventStartDate']));
    $date = explode(' ', $rawdate);

    $postlink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $row['eventTitle']))); 

    echo "<div class=\"event\">
            <div class=\"txt\">
                <h5><a href='/" . $postlink ."'>" . $row['eventTitle'] . "&sbquo;&nbsp;" . $date[1] ."&nbsp;" . $date[0] . "</h5></a>
                <p>" . $shortdesc ."&hellip;&nbsp;
                <a href=\"" . $postlink . "\">find out more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><img src='/wp-content/uploads/". $thumburl[0] ."-42x42.jpg' alt='". $row['eventTitle'] ."' />
        </div>";
        echo _clear('15');   
 }
```

as far as i can tell.

Comment: Did you notice the second loop uses `$result2` and `$row2`, whereas the first loop uses `$result` and `$row`..?

Comment: Thanks for your response Matt. Although, I was already getting the correct result I wanted from the way it was, I was just only getting one result rather than two returned. I tried the way you suggested but it just returns the exact same result as my original code.

Comment: @Rijk yes, but did you notice $thumburl is used below?

Comment: @Ben Gordon ok try this `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2); echo "$num_rows Rows\n";` and see how many rows it does return.

Comment: @Ben Gordon, what query should you be getting 2 in? the first query or second query?

Comment: @Matt I also don't think it's anything to do with the second query/while loop as I still get the same result without it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3209/discussion-between-ben-gordon-and-matt)